# Download subtitles from TED talks for offline viewing

Tags: video, subtitles

I'm wondering if it's possible to download [subtitles for the TED talks](http://blog.ted.com/2009/05/ted_open_trans.php) for offline viewing.

**Related on Stack Overflow**
[Parsing and Converting TED Talks JSON Subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955618/parsing-and-converting-ted-talks-json-subtitles).

Comment: Think you need to check with TED for that. The talks are available in many languages, but that's as part of the flash experience, so I can't see how to extract the subtitles. Nice idea though.

Comment: See https://github.com/oxplot/ted2mkv
It lets you download a TED talk to an mkv file with all the subtitles/metadata embedded in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer just a hint . I have found the URL which loads the related file like this , and its in JSON format.

http://www.ted.com/talks/titles/id/451/lang/hin

Comment: It's `http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/451/lang/hin` but thanks very much for the tip! I'm going to see how I can convert those to a compatible format now.

Comment: Are you saying it's both not a hint nor an answer?

Comment: ha ha , Fixed :)

Answer (score 7):

I made a app to solve this:

http://tedtalksubtitledownload.appspot.com

Comment: Well, now it doesn't work

Comment: should be working now, @develop7.

Comment: It does not work for now.

Comment: fixed again! it stopped working because of TED's ui changes

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this URL:

http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/33/lang/en

- change **33** to the correct topic id
- change **en** to the language you require

into [json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com)

and you will be able to download a nicely formatted spreadsheet of the subtitles per time stamp.